# Missing .bashrc file Terminal not working

Tags: terminal

Terminal is not accepting any commands and I suspect it is due to a missing .bashrc that I couldn't find in the home directory. Please help me restore it without the use of the command line, as it is severely unresponsive!

Comment: The `~/.bashrc` file does not exist by default, so if it's missing, it's no big deal. Does `/etc/bashrc` exist?

Comment: ~/.bashrc doesn't run for login shells (the kind Terminal normally starts with), so it's irrelevant anyway. Instead, it runs one of: ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bask_login, or ~/.profile. Do any of these exist, and if so what do they contain?

Comment: Thank you both! I found out somehow visual studio code had wrecked my .bash_profile.txt and repeated the same line for hundreds of lines.. Had to find a sample .bash_profile.txt online and rewrite it. Weird